# Trying to authenticate with email

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to set a user as authenticated when they login. Whenever I attempt to authenticate them it returns `None`. I'm assuming it's because I'm using an email and not a username?

```
#views.py
def login(request):
    email = request.POST.get("email", "")
    password = request.POST.get("password", "")

    flancer = Freelancer.objects.get(email=email)

    user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)


#models.py
class Freelancer(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, primary_key=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    university = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: which version of Django are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.8.4

Comment: The Django docs [has a guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) for creating a custom user model that uses the email address as the user name.

Comment: @Alasdair you should post that as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

This gets a bit tricky when you move from the default settings. I might not have the full answer for you without seeing settings.py.

AUTH_USER_MODEL=appname.freelancer'

I would also look at importing the user model:

impo django.contrib.auth.models,

class Freelancer(AbstractBaseUser):

Answer (score 0):

Authentication with email addresses is quite complicated with Django. At the moment, there are too many issues with your code (e.g. unencrypted password field) to fix in a Stack Overflow answer.

The Django docs [has a guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) for creating a custom user model that uses the email address as the user name. I recommend you work through that and come back to Stack Overflow with any specific questions that you have.

You can then use the built in [authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views), instead of writing your own login view.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the unencrypted password issue. I'll be coming back to that shortly. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.micahcarrick.com/django-email-authentication.html

Helpful in this case ...

For deep information follow
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/